# When do I use curly brackets and when not?

Tags: c#, function, brackets

Today they handed me over a old project someone has worked on for quite some time. Something I noticed was the inconsistency in when they use curly brackets and when not. So my question now is, are there any rules in when you use them and when not?

Little example of what I mean:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        BcFeedLeftOver other = obj as BcFeedLeftOver;
        if (other != null)
            return (_date.CompareTo(other.Date));
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a BcFeedLeftover");
    }
```

This is the original function as you can see no use of curly brackets.
But in a lot of other functions like this one he does use them, even if the `if` statement only executes 1 line of code like in the example above.

Comment: From Programmers: [Single statement if block - braces or no?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/16528/16620)

Comment: Actually there are "official" coding gudes. You can find them here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx. Of course these are just guides, not rules.

Comment: I think this question does not deserve closing for last revision. Voted for re-open.

Comment: remember apples ssl bug? if not you can easily find it using google and "goto fail". if the dev had used curlies in that code the bug would never have existed... which is to say: for safety reasons it's generally advisable to use curly braces to properly define where a scope starts and ends, even if it seems redundant.

Comment: I suppose that the inconsistencies come from whether or not more code was either there during tests or might conceivable be added (again).. The example certainly could use the braces, imo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to if your `if` statement spans multiple commands. If not, it is free to you to determine when to use it or not.

Some might find always adding curly brackets a good standard for readability or code safety, others don't and tend to only use them when they need to. It is totally up to you!

I tend to always use brackets. It is easier to mess up things if you don't add them. If you add them, you are always sure the body of the `if` statement works as expected and that adding a single line doesn't mess up everything.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i was out of town and unable to react. I myself am also used to always add brackets and never bother doing not so. but when viewing this code i saw it happen alot at some places but other places not, this somewhat confused me. But this helped, seems like i will just keep on adding them since i find it easier to see stuff, and probably because of error reasons, Thanks alot sir !